# ADF : Null pointer when accessing application module in Managed Bean

Tags: oracle-adf

I am accessing the applyViewCriteria method written in VoImpl class from the managed bean. The code snippet is something like:

```
 EmployeeAppModuleImpl appModule= new EmployeeAppModuleImpl();                       
 ViewObject vo = appModule.findViewObject("EmployeesView");
```

I have the EmployeeAppModuleImpl class in which the EmployessView accessor methods are generated.
 The "appModule" returned is null. I seem to be missing something important.
Please help!

Comment: You doing it wrong. Use bindings.

Comment: I tried this as well but the view object is returned null however i access application module:

Comment: DCBindingContainer bindings = (DCBindingContainer) BindingContext.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry();
                             
                         DCIteratorBinding dcItteratorBindings =
                             bindings.findIteratorBinding("EmployeesViewIterator");
                         DCIteratorBinding empIter =
                            bindings.findIteratorBinding("EmployeesView1Iterator");
                            ViewObject voemp = dcItteratorBindings.getViewObject();

Comment: Does the VO work in the BC Tester?  Also (use cases vary) it can be easier to expose the VO impl methods on the AM and then call that from its DataControl. Then you do not need to access the iterator and have a bunch of code. Do you get data if you drag and drop the VO from the data control onto the page? I would start my testing there.

Comment: @Joe has described what I said in short. Expose method, make an operation binding, execute it from the bean.

Comment: I do get the data when i drag and drop from the VO.
I ran it from BC tester and the viewCriteria also works. it is just that whenever i try accessing the viewObject. it is returning null in the AMImpl.